# Selecionar valores de uma coluna a partir de outras colunas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Estou tentando selecionar somente os valores da coluna *flightID* onde *DepDelay* e *ArrDelay* são maiores que 15.

Tentei isso:

```
delay = data.loc[(data['ArrDelay'] > 15) & (data['DepDelay'] > 15), ['FlightID']]
```

Mas não deu certo...

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-11d40b8188f5> in <module>()
      1 #delay = data.loc['FlightID']
      2 
----> 3 delay = data.loc[(data['ArrDelay'] > 15) & (data['DepDelay'] > 15), ['FlightID']]

C:\Programmes\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1365             except (KeyError, IndexError):
   1366                 pass
-> 1367             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1368         else:
   1369             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

C:\Programmes\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    861 
    862         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers
--> 863         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
    864 
    865         # ugly hack for GH #836

C:\Programmes\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    202             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
    203                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
--> 204             if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
    205                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can only have "
    206                                  "[{types}] types"

C:\Programmes\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_type(self, key, axis)
   1470                         raise KeyError(
   1471                             u"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis}]".format(
-> 1472                                 key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
   1473                     else:
   1474 

KeyError: "None of [['FlightID']] are in the [columns]"
```

**Eu estava esperando:**

```
flightID         DepDelay   ArrDelay
BBYYEUVY67527    20.0           64.0   
MUPXAQFN40227    17.0           52.0  
KTAMHIFO10843    16.0           18.0
```

(ou somente os três valores da coluna *flightID*)

**Dados**

```
flightID         Month  ArrTime ActualElapsedTime  DepDelay   ArrDelay
BBYYEUVY67527        1   1514.0               58.0     20.0      64.0   
MUPXAQFN40227        1     37.0              120.0     17.0      52.0   
LQLYUIMN79169        1    916.0              166.0       NA     -25.0   
KTAMHIFO10843        1      NaN                NaN      5.0       NaN   
BOOXJTEY23623        1      NaN                NaN      4.0       NaN  
BBYYEUVY67527        2   1514.0               58.0       NA      64.0   
MUPXAQFN40227        2     37.0              120.0       NA      52.0   
LQLYUIMN79169        2    916.0              166.0       NA     -25.0   
KTAMHIFO10843        2      NaN                NaN     16.0      18.0   
BOOXJTEY23623        2      NaN                NaN        4       NaN
```

Comment: A resposta em baixo está correta, mas um pouco incompleta, experimenta `..., ['flightID']]` em vez de `..., ['FlightID']]` e vai dar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coluna FlightID não existe, como descrito pelo keyError

```
KeyError: "None of [['FlightID']] are in the [columns]"
```

Você pode ter se enganado ao copiar aqui o nome das colunas. Verifique no seu DataFrame.